# Full text + spatial search with Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Let's say I have a SQL 2005 database with a table called Restaurants. The Restaurants table has the following columns:

- RestaurantId
- Name
- Latitude
- Longitude

I want to let users search for restaurants by name and/or address. How do I write the LINQ query to support this? I need to be able to support the possibility that the user doesn't enter in a name or address, just the name, just the address, or both name and address.

My initial idea was to write a stored procedure to calculate the distance between two lat/long pairs and a table value function for calling FREETEXTTABLE and using some conditional Join calls on my query. However, it appears that Entity Framework 4 doesn't support table value functions.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can write [a proc which returns entity types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896279.aspx). Indeed, in EF 1 that was the only option for procs. The proc returns a set of values, not a table, but I can't see that you actually need this.

You can also do free-form T-SQL in EF 4 using [Context.ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx).

Comment: Just to confirm -- with `ExecuteStoreQuery`, further LINQ operations will use the LINQ-to-Objects operators? In other words, if I call `.Where` on the results of `ExecuteStoreQuery` the results will be filtered in-memory and not on the server?

Comment: @ZevSpitz `ExecuteStoreQuery` returns `ObjectResult<T>` which implements `IEnumerable<T>`, but not `IQueryable<T>`. Hence, further LINQ operations indeed are in L2O, not L2E.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write any `LINQ` that supports *geospatial queries* at this point of time - be it `EF` or `LinqToSql`. This is because there is no `LINQ` syntax which can handle the special `ST<whatever>` spatial syntax that exists in SQL Server 2008. (eg. `STIntersects(..)`)

You will need to write a **Stored Procedure** which you can then get access to via `EF`.

If you wish to return a `Sql GEOGRAPHY` field in a result, you will need to return a `VARBINARY(MAX)` i think as the equivalent field type for the `C#` code.

Hope This Helps.